# Does collecting apples do anything?

Tags: here-comes-niko

Is there any reason to collect apples in *Here Comes Niko*? I've collected over 600 of them but I haven't been able to find a use for them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's a hidden unlockable use for apples on the final stage.

There's a horse named Master standing by a dojo on the side of Tadpole Inc's game development building. They will teach you how to super jump in exchange for 250 apples.

A super jump will use 10 apples. Press and hold the jump button until Niko is fully squished then release.

[image: the horse named master]